# HTML + CSS Image link won't work after moving the image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, position

Basically i want to position my Image under my name(in my website which is in the middle of the screen) when i move the image DOWN the link no longer works, i can move it left or right as much as i want and it works! but up and down, it no longer works?

HTML:

```
<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/clarkycalLad/" target="_blank">
  <div class="imgtest">
    <img src="/images/steam-icon.png" alt="HTML tutorial" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.imgtest {
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that as written. Perhaps you've moved it so far down there's another element on top of it now?

Comment: Its Weird because that doesnt make sense? i move it down to where its just below the middle of the screen..

Comment: Since we can't see any more of your page, there's no real way to give any more specific recommendation.

Comment: Would you like to see my FULL Html and Css?

Comment: If you setup a jsfiddle where we can actually see the result, that'd be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:
I fixed it by adding:

```
    z-index: 1;
```

To my css part of the image/Link

So before it was

```
    .imgtest {
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Now its:

```
.imgtest {
    position: relative;
    left: 800px;
    top: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps others!
Thanks for those who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I just got it: it's not that the image doesn't show up; it's that it's not a link.

You want this:

```
<div class="imgtest">
  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/clarkycalLad/" target="_blank">
    <img src="/images/steam-icon.png" alt="HTML tutorial" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Otherwise you're moving the image but not the anchor.